# Class literals in Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, el

I've found the literal expressions available in JSP EL listed here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77280

While most literals available in Java are available in EL, notably absent are character and class literals (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Writing

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE: ${Integer.MAX_VALUE}
```

displays fine, but when I try

```
Integer.class: ${Integer.class}
```

I get

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Either 'class' is not a public static field of the class 'java.lang.Integer' or field is inaccessible
    at javax.el.StaticFieldELResolver.getValue(StaticFieldELResolver.java:106)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    ...
```

I'd really like to be able to pass a value like this into a custom tag. Is there any way to get this value in a JSP other than writing it in a Java Expression?

Comment: Either 'class' is not a public static field of the class 'java.lang.Integer' or field is inaccessible. There is NO field class in java.lang.Integer

Comment: @GCP In other words you've never heard of class literals. See [JLS #15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

Comment: @EJP Well you learn something new every day, I thought he is trying to access a non existing field named after a keyword that he thought was in the java.lang.Integer